# vim saving .php files takes a long time

Tags: php, vim

I'm using vim 8.0 and it takes roughly 5-10 seconds to write to a .php file of any size. I haven't found any other file extensions that have the same issue.

Are there any vim config settings or plugins that have been known to cause this?

EDIT: Adding my plugins

- YouCompleteMe
- ctrlp.vim
- editorconfig-vim
- emmet-vim
- nerdtree
- php.vim
- syntastic
- tern_for_vim
- typescript-vim
- vim-es6
- vim-indent-guides
- vim-javascript
- vim-jsdoc
- vim-json

Comment: Do you use GitGutter?

Comment: I imagine you have a plugin which is causing this slow down. Maybe enable/disable your plugins a few at a time until you can isolate the offending plugin

Comment: @SyntacticFructose I don't.

Comment: @PeterRincker that's what I figured. I'll edit with my plugins.

Comment: Syntastic would be the most obvious.